# Generic CompletableFuture and complete

Tags: java, generics

I built a class to send requests and receive responses from server.

```
public class RequestManager {
    private final Map<String, CompletableFuture> requests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public <T extends Response> void callback(String reqId, T resp) {
        this.requests.get(reqId).complete(resp);
    }

    public <T extends Response> CompletableFuture<T> sendAsync(Request req) {
        CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        String reqId = this.generateRequestId();
        this.requests.put(reqId, future);
        return future;
    }

    // omitted
}
```

This class works fine. But once I specific the type for the `CompletableFuture` in the `Map` to be `Map<String, CompletableFuture<? extends Response>>`, the compiler starts to complaining the `complete(resp)` line saying

```
Required type: captures of ? extends Response
Provided: T
```

This is very confusing to me since `T` is also defined as `T extends Response`. How shall I do it properly?

EDIT:

However, if I set the type in `Map` to `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Response>>` or `Map<String, CompletableFuture<? super Response>>` (as suggested by @tentacle and @ttzn), I get error when adding stuffs to the `Map` at `this.requests.put(reqId, future);`:

```
Required type: CompletableFuture<? super Response>
Provided: CompletableFuture
<T>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider making your entire class parametrized.

```
public class RequestManager<T extends Response> {
    private Map<String, CompletableFuture<T>> requests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void callback(String reqId, T resp) {
        this.requests.get(reqId).complete(resp);
    }
}
```

In this case types of callback method and requests map are consistent and derived from enclosing class.

Alternatively, you could change requests declaration to:

```
Map<String, CompletableFuture<? super Response>> requests = new...
```

edit:
And for put part of latter solution:

```
void create(String s, CompletableFuture<? super Response> resp) {
    getRequests().put(s, resp);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the type would not be consistent for each callback method... Your solution does work for `requests.get()`, but it cause new issue for `requests.put()`. Could you check the updated question to see what I shall do? Thank you.

Comment: The put part is also fixable in the same way, I've updated my answer. You also can always use class casts when you really stumbled with generics inconsistency, but it's really a last resort kind of solution and  should be avoided at all costs.
I generally try to avoid generic methods for non-static context. Parametrized class is almost always the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two sibling subclasses of `Response`, for instance `ByteResponse` and `IntResponse`. With what you wrote, the following would compile:

```
CompletableFuture<ByteResponse> byteRequest = new CompletableFuture<>();
requests.put("id", byteRequest);
callback("id", new IntResponse());
```

`byteRequest` could be accessed somewhere else in the code, and someone calling `get()` would be in for a nasty surprise.

You cannot feed `T extends Response` to an instance that consumes `? extends Response` because that instance might be expecting a totally different subtype than `T`. In fact, the only thing that you can pass is null. Depending on what you want to do, you should be fine with `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Response>>`. Use `? super Response` if you really want your map of requests to be the most generic possible.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, change it to `? super Response` cause new error when putting stuffs into the map. Could you check the updated question to see what I shall do? Thank you.

Comment: The point of my answer is that you simply cannot use `CompletableFuture<T extends Response>` because of what your `callback()` method does. So `sendAsync` needs to return a `CompletableFuture<T super Response>` or simply `CompletableFuture<Response>`. This is the best you can do.